# How to call Filter for needed Resource Controller actions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a resource controller `Items`:

```
Route::resource('items', 'ItemsController');
```

And in action `ItemsController@store` for creating new item i'm need to activate `CSRF filter` (and maybe `Auth filter`) before actions with form. But i can't write

```
$this->beforeFilter('csrf')
```

it doesn't works. It works when I put this calling in parent Controller's `__construct()`.

What I need to do to call some filters directly for resource controller actions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be able to use the filters for specific actions only by setting it in the `__construct()` like this:

```
class ItemsController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on' => 'store') );
    }

    //rest of controller... 
}
```

Note - You can also use the keywords "only" and "except" and pass an array of action names to apply (or negate) the filter for more than one action.

Comment: `only` option helps me. Thanks!

Comment: For those interested: http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#controller-filters explains the usage of adding filters in a controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just normally use `Route::resource()` constructor. Use this code:

```
Route::resource('items', 'ItemsController', ['before' => 'csrf']);
```